# iOS Emulator for Windows

Tags: windows, ios, windows-10, emulator

I'm looking for an iOS emulator for Windows. I would like this software to meet the following requirements:

- Works on Windows 10
- Emulates latest iOS (Currently, 9)
- Runs iOS apps
- Emulates an iPad
- Interface is English

Some features that are not requirements but wanted are:

- Can emulate either/both an iPhone and an iPad mini
- Gratis
- Has access to the App Store

Comment: AFAIK there aren't any (any that actually work, I mean). Even Apple doesn't make one. (The Android development kit comes with an emulator: a program that emulates the hardware of a phone/tablet, on which the actual OS is running. Apple's devkit comes with a simulator: you can compile your source code to link against libraries that provide the iOS APIs and run that on your x86 processor.)

Comment: @Gilles Sure, I haven't heard of any myself, but I figured if anyone did, this would be the place to ask

Answer (score 2):

There is absolutely no possible way that you can run iOS 9, with the full App Store at all, if a solution did exist, I'd be really surprised.

**The closest to get iOS on a PC** is to install Mac OS X in a virtual machine (that is if your PC is even compatible), then using the Mac App Store to install Xcode(which is a software development it). Xcode comes with a iOS simulator. Then you'd make a blank iOS app within Xcode, and run it. This would open the iOS simulator, and therefore have a iOS simulator/emulator.

This would take a while to setup and depending on your PC specs, might not work. Also, you'd need a Mac OS X ISO file and a copy of VMware or VirtualBox. So depending on how important this is, it might not be worth it.

Comment: [iOS simulator isn't emulator and can't run ARM code.](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/113055/22781)

Answer (score 1):

As far as I am aware, there are no emulators that will actually emulate a real iPhone/Pad.  There is [iPadian](http://www.ipadian.net/) (I have never used it), which says that it will run iOS apps, but that appears to have its own app store, and it certainly looks nothing like iOS.

Comment: Exactly, they do have their own app store with a **very** limited amount of apps, moreover they have no way that I could find to use my own app and at least in the past it has contained malware :/ (I don't know if it still does but if anyone were to use it, run it in either a sandbox or vm)